# ChainedTransactionManager calling AfterCompletion in different thread

Tags: spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-transactions, spring-kafka

I'm using a `ChainedTransactionManager` with `KafkaTransactionManager` and `JpaTransactionManager`. And I'm using a Thread Local variable to hold an id.

And I have a flow like this:

HTTP call => HTTP Filter (sets TL var) => logic that sends a Spring Event => TransactionalEventListener(phase = BeforeCommit) receives it and sends it to kafka (uses interceptor to add TL as event header and cleans TL)

That's what **should** be happening, but this is what is happening.

... => logic that sends a Spring Event => **another event takes the thread, finishes, cleans the TL** => goes back to the event listener, receives the event, but at this point the TL is clear and the kafka publishing fails.

All of this happens in the same thread. Although Spring Events should be synchronous (except that you use `@Async`, which I don't), the `TransactionalEventListener` is being called in another thread.

What I mean by "another event takes the thread" is that the current consumer thread finishes (although it didn't really finish because the listener code is still missing), and that same thread is used by another consumer, to consume another event. When this last event has been consumed, that thread goes back to the TxnEventListener with the TL cleared.

This is the exception stacktrace:

```
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.ProducerInterceptors.onSend(ProducerInterceptors.java:61)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer.send(KafkaProducer.java:855)
    at org.springframework.kafka.core.DefaultKafkaProducerFactory$CloseSafeProducer.send(DefaultKafkaProducerFactory.java:569)
    at io.opentracing.contrib.kafka.TracingKafkaProducer.send(TracingKafkaProducer.java:116)
    at io.opentracing.contrib.kafka.TracingKafkaProducer.send(TracingKafkaProducer.java:97)
    at org.springframework.kafka.core.KafkaTemplate.doSend(KafkaTemplate.java:404)
    at org.springframework.kafka.core.KafkaTemplate.send(KafkaTemplate.java:222)
    at org.springframework.kafka.core.KafkaTemplate.sendDefault(KafkaTemplate.java:200)
    at revisions.messaging.publisher.implementation.RevisionsKafkaPublisher.sendDefault(RevisionsKafkaPublisher.kt:8)
    at revisions.messaging.publisher.implementation.RevisionsEventsPublisher.handle(RevisionsEventsPublisher.kt:17)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.springframework.context.event.ApplicationListenerMethodAdapter.doInvoke(ApplicationListenerMethodAdapter.java:300)
    at org.springframework.context.event.ApplicationListenerMethodAdapter.processEvent(ApplicationListenerMethodAdapter.java:190)
    at org.springframework.transaction.event.ApplicationListenerMethodTransactionalAdapter$TransactionSynchronizationEventAdapter.processEvent(ApplicationListenerMethodTransactionalAdapter.java:129)
    at org.springframework.transaction.event.ApplicationListenerMethodTransactionalAdapter$TransactionSynchronizationEventAdapter.afterCompletion(ApplicationListenerMethodTransactionalAdapter.java:118)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionSynchronizationUtils.invokeAfterCompletion(TransactionSynchronizationUtils.java:171)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.invokeAfterCompletion(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:990)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.triggerAfterCompletion(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:965)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.processCommit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:786)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.commit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:712)
    at org.springframework.data.transaction.MultiTransactionStatus.commit(MultiTransactionStatus.java:74)
    at org.springframework.data.transaction.ChainedTransactionManager.commit(ChainedTransactionManager.java:150)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionTemplate.execute(TransactionTemplate.java:152)
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.invokeRecordListenerInTx(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1418)
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.invokeRecordListener(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1398)
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.invokeListener(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1165)
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.pollAndInvoke(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:949)
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.run(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:884)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Is there a way to avoid calling the `AfterCompletion` on another thread? The event handling is synchronous, no `@Async` or anything similar. I don't need the multiple threads for consuming a request/event.

I think there's something with the Transaction Synchronization and the ChainedTransactionManager but I don't know what.

Thanks!

Comment: It;s not clear what you are saying; what does `another event takes the thread` mean? Threads aren't "taken". You need to show your code and configuration. Transactions are thread-bound.

Comment: What I meant was that the current consumer thread finishes (although it didn't really finish because the listener code is still missing), and that same thread is used by another consumer, to consume another event. When this last event has been consumed, that thread goes back to the TxnEventListener with the TL cleared.

Comment: Again; you need to show your code - it's too hard to guess what your code looks like. It makes no sense for a thread to be re-used before the transaction is committed or rolled back.

Comment: I will add some code tomorrow. I found something vaguely similar here https://github.com/mybatis/spring/issues/18. But I don't know if it's related.